# ¿Como pasar datos entre Includes en una misma consulta de sequelize?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

tengo un inconveniente con sequelize, necesito consultar varias tablas en una misma consulta, estas las anido con **Include:[]** hasta ahí muy bien, pero necesito pasar el resultado de una tabla anidada (monedas) a otra tabla de otro include (precios), ya que con respecto a ese valor de la tabla monedas se debe hacer un WHERE en la tabla precios.

Codigo de ejemplo:

```
db.tiendas.findAll({
  where : {id_tienda: '4'},
  attributes: ['id_tienda'],
  include : [
    {
      model : db.cuentas,       
      as : "cuentas",
      attributes: ['id_cuenta','numero'],
      required: false,
      include : [
        {
          model : db.monedas, // MONEDAS
          as : "monedas",
          attributes: ['id_moneda'], // este valor es el que se tiene que pasar a la tabla precios ubicada mas abajo
          required: false                      
        }
      ]      
    },
    {
      model : db.programas, 
      as : "programas",
      attributes: ['titulo'],
      required: false,     
      include : [          
        {
          model : db.precios, //PRECIOS 
          as : "precio"
          where: {id_moneda: /*aqui necesito el id_moneda*/ }]},
          attributes: ['valor'],
          through: { attributes: [] },
          required: false         
        }
      ]
    }]}).then((datos)=>{console.log(datos)})
```

Gracias por el tiempo prestado.

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo haría, es poner un subquery en el where, algo como esto:

```
 db.tiendas.findAll({
  where : {id_tienda: '4'},
  attributes: ['id_tienda'],
  include : [
    {
      model : db.cuentas,       
      as : "cuentas",
      attributes: ['id_cuenta','numero'],
      required: false,
      include : [
        {
          model : db.monedas, // MONEDAS
          as : "monedas",
          attributes: ['id_moneda'], // este valor es el que se tiene que pasar a la tabla precios ubicada mas abajo
          required: false                      
        }
      ]      
    },
    {
      model : db.programas, 
      as : "programas",
      attributes: ['titulo'],
      required: false,     
      include : [          
        {
          model : db.precios, //PRECIOS 
          as : "precio"
          where: {id_moneda: db.sequelize.literal('(select id_moneda from cuentas where id_tienda = 4)') },
          attributes: ['valor'],
          through: { attributes: [] },
          required: false         
        }
      ]
    }
  ]}).then((datos)=>{console.log(datos)})
```

Necesitaría ver la estructura de tus tablas para saber bien el subquery, pero creo que esto te podría ayudar.

Saludos